# Add a counter to Angular ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

I am trying to find some documentation for being able to append a counted number to each item returned by an ng-repeat. Is this not an out of a box thing for Angular? Not quite like an Id, but more like, if 4 items returned, each item JSON object could add a number in front of data returned. My code looks like:

```
<div  class="swipeBoxes" ng-repeat="swipe in swipes">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="swipeBox">
            <span class="swipeNum"></span>
            <p><span>swipe date:</span><span>{{ swipe.date | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy'}}</span></p>
            <p><span>provider:</span><span>{{ swipe.merchant }}</span></p>
            <p><span>amount:</span><span>{{ swipe.amount | currency }}</span></p>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: you can use `$index` inside of an `ng-repeat`...is this what you are looking for?

Comment: <div ng-repeat="swipe in swipes track by $index">

Comment: Right in the documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [$index](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) for your counter.

```
<div  class="swipeBoxes" ng-repeat="swipe in swipes">
    {{$index + 1}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `$index` from [ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) should be able to solve your problems.